# Bracha on Kiddush Hachodesh

Tags: blessing, mitzvah, calendar, tractate-brachot, rosh-chodesh-new-month

Did the beit din make a bracha each month on the mitzvah of kiddush hachodesh in the times of the Sanhedrin? If yes, what was the language of the bracha?

Comment: [This article from R' Zvi Ryzman](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php/%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%99:%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%97%D7%95%D7%93%D7%A9_(Zvi_Ryzman)) cites *T'fillas David* (p. 55) by the Aderet: "ולי נראה שאולי יש לומר שבעת שקידשו החודש בוודאי היו מברכים עליו, וככל מצוות שבתורה. והכי נמי הוא מצות עשה דהחודש הזה לכם. ואם כן היו עומדים בעת הברכה ככל ברכת המצוות, כמש"כ המג"א (או"ח סי' ח ס"ק ב), וממילא גם המצוה בעצמה".